# How to properly escape reserved regex characters in JSON?

Tags: python, json, regex

I have a JSON file that contains some regex expressions that I want to use in my python code.
The problem arises when I try to escape reserved regex characters in the JSON file.
When I run the python code, it can't process the json file and throws an exception.

I have already debugged the code and come to the conclusion, that it fails when calling `json.loads(ruleFile.read())`. Apparently only some characters can be escaped in JSON and the dot is not one of them which causes a syntax error.

```py
try:
    with open(args.rules, "r") as ruleFile:
        rules = json.loads(ruleFile.read())
        for rule in rules:
            rules[rule] = re.compile(rules[rule])
except (IOError, ValueError) as e:
    raise Exception("Error reading rules file")
```

```
{
    "Rule 1": "www\.[a-z]{3,10}\.com"
}
```

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 375, in <module>
    main()
  File "foo.py", line 67, in main
    raise Exception("Error reading rules file")
Exception: Error reading rules file
```

How do I work around this JSON syntax problem?

Comment: Probably need a double backslash to escape the backslash in the string: `"www\\.[a-z]{3,10}\\.com"`

Comment: Then it gets processed as "www.[a-z]{3,10}.com". The dot is interpreted as a reserved character and not as a dot.

Comment: Try using the double backslash in your JSON, and then print out the rule before compiling the regex. You should see only a single backslash remaining.

Comment: Nevermind, it works now. I probably messed up the first time with the double backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash needs to be escaped in JSON.

```
{
    "Rule 1": "www\\.[a-z]{3,10}\\.com"
}
```

From [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html):

> The following characters are reserved in JSON and must be properly
>   escaped to be used in strings:
>
> - **Backspace** is replaced with **\b**
> - **Form feed** is replaced with **\f**
> - **Newline** is replaced with **\n**
> - **Carriage return** is replaced with **\r**
> - **Tab** is replaced with **\t**
> - **Double quote** is replaced with **\"**
> - **Backslash** is replaced with **\\**

Answer (score 1):

The rule is to first have a correct string in a correct dictionary. And `\` are to be escapes in Python.

So you should initially write:

```
rules = {"Rule 1": r"www\.[a-z]{3,10}\.com"}
```

You can then easily convert that to a JSON string:

```
print(json.dumps(rules, indent=4))

{
    "Rule 1": "www\\.[a-z]{3,10}\\.com"
}
```

You now know how the json file containing the regexes should be formatted.